# ReactNative ld: library not found for -lboost_context

Tags: react-native

Please Help, I am getting this error when I am trying to build my react native ios app

`ld: library not found for -lboost_context`

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me after upgrade Flipper to the latest version.

In my case, I have fixed this by following this.

open **project.xcworkspace** on **Build Phases** tab > **Link Binary With Libraries** > **+** (*add items*) > then you will see "**boost_context.xcframework**"

[fig01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyibe.png)

Comment: I have got the same error but even after trying the solution you provided here, it's still showing the same error after build